# MapReduce (Hadoop-2.6.0)+ HBase-1.0.1.1 class not found exception

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I have written a Map-Reduce program to fetch data from an input file and output it to a HBase table. But I am not able to execute. I am getting the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration
        at beginners.VisitorSort.main(VisitorSort.java:123)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/TableReducer
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at visitor.HitTimeGmt.main(HitTimeGmt.java:142)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableReducer
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

**I am not sharing the code, as I know this is an classpath issue. The same code ran on Hadoop-1.3.1 and Hbase-0.94.8 versions. Have updated the jars in the build classpath in eclipse, in bashrc file, in Hadoop-env.sh and also in hbase-env.sh.**

But still I am facing this issue. I am out of options now. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you adding the jars. Using maven?

Comment: No. Adding them in the build path in eclipse

Comment: You are running in local(eclipse) or cluster

Comment: I am exporting the jar and running in the cluster

Comment: So if running in cluster, does your jar have access to those hadoop jars. You mentioned above that you updated the classpath in eclipse. Are you including hadoop jars as part of your jar(like fat jar), or are you trying to use the jars in cluster.

Comment: I am including the hadoop and hbase jars in my program jar only.

Comment: ok the above class is in hbase-common-0.98.0.2.1.2.0-402-hadoop2. Version might vary. As you are adding them separately, please check if all the dependencies are there in the jar. using maven could be better, as it resolves the dependencies.

Comment: Yeah. It's there in my classpath. Hbase-common-1.0.1.1.jar  any idea which jar contains TableReducer class?

Comment: Its in hbase-server. In eclipse, you can use Ctrl+Shft+T, and search for the type. There you can all the references of that type with jars. Happy coding :)

Comment: Now i get the following exception                                                         Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/TableReducer

Comment: As I mentioned above, it should be in the hbase-server jar. If you manually add jars, this process continues, until your project has all dependent jars. Maven can come to the rescue. or else, please get the complete list of jars needed to run your Hbase program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, solved the issue. Needed to add the following line in hadoop-env.sh(all nodes)

```
HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HBASE_HOME/lib/*
```